# Update Last Invoice number in Customer View(res.partner)

Tags: odoo

I have created a custom module in Odoo. I want to display a read only field in customer view(res.partner form view) where the last invoice id must be updated as soon as a new invoice of that customer is created and validated.

Which method should I refer in `account.invoice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should override ORM *create()* method of *account.invoice* object.

Try with this code.

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):


        #call super method
        invoice = super(AccountInvoice,self).create(vals)

        #update partner field with lastest created invoice
        invoice.partner_id.your_field_name = invoice.number

        return invoice
```

For more [Odoo technical reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html)

Comment: Will it be a link to the invoice or just a text??

Comment: I have written answer as per *char* type of *your_field_name*. If you want to add link then you can. You need to set one Many2one field in *res.partner* object. As in answer we have returned *invoice.number* will be replaced with *invoice.id*